# Read XML Data From sql server Table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following XML column with this data:

```
<Motion>
     <LimitationTypes>
        <LimitationTypeId>6</LimitationTypeId>
        <LimitationTypeId>5</LimitationTypeId>
        <LimitationTypeId>4</LimitationTypeId>
        <LimitationTypeId>3</LimitationTypeId>
    </LimitationTypes>
</Motion>
```

How can I get the output as table with 4 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following script:

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<Motion>
                 <LimitationTypes>
                    <LimitationTypeId>6</LimitationTypeId>
                    <LimitationTypeId>5</LimitationTypeId>
                    <LimitationTypeId>4</LimitationTypeId>
                    <LimitationTypeId>3</LimitationTypeId>
                </LimitationTypes>
            </Motion>'

SELECT
    a.b.value('LimitationTypes[1]/LimitationTypeId[1]','varchar(10)') AS LimitationTypeId1,
    a.b.value('LimitationTypes[1]/LimitationTypeId[2]','varchar(10)') AS LimitationTypeId2,
    a.b.value('LimitationTypes[1]/LimitationTypeId[3]','varchar(10)') AS LimitationTypeId3,
    a.b.value('LimitationTypes[1]/LimitationTypeId[4]','varchar(10)') AS LimitationTypeId4
FROM @MyXML.nodes('Motion') a(b)
```

to get the following result:

[image]

The following would work as well and you get to write `LimitationTypes` only once:

```
SELECT
    a.b.value('LimitationTypeId[1]','varchar(10)') AS LimitationTypeId1,
    a.b.value('LimitationTypeId[2]','varchar(10)') AS LimitationTypeId2,
    a.b.value('LimitationTypeId[3]','varchar(10)') AS LimitationTypeId3,
    a.b.value('LimitationTypeId[4]','varchar(10)') AS LimitationTypeId4
FROM @MyXML.nodes('Motion/LimitationTypes') a(b)
```

You can read more about the `nodes()` method on [nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type)
.

> EDIT:

For rows, this could be done:

```
SELECT
    'LimitationTypeId1' as col, a.b.value('LimitationTypeId[1]','varchar(10)') AS val
FROM @MyXML.nodes('Motion/LimitationTypes') a(b)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'LimitationTypeId2' as col, a.b.value('LimitationTypeId[2]','varchar(10)') AS val
FROM @MyXML.nodes('Motion/LimitationTypes') a(b)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'LimitationTypeId3' as col, a.b.value('LimitationTypeId[3]','varchar(10)') AS val
FROM @MyXML.nodes('Motion/LimitationTypes') a(b)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'LimitationTypeId4' as col, a.b.value('LimitationTypeId[4]','varchar(10)') AS val
FROM @MyXML.nodes('Motion/LimitationTypes') a(b)
```

Comment: i think he/she needs four rows, not four columns

Comment: can i get the answers in 4 rows?